# Xugller illegalArgumentExeception

Tags: converters, processing, illegalargumentexception, xuggler

I'm try to convert a movie (.mp4) in audio (.mp3) with Xuggler. I use porcessing on OS X.

```
 IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("/Users/nouv/Desktop/video1.mp4");
 IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("/Users/nouv/Desktop/audioOutput.mp3", reader);
 int sampleRate = 22050;
 int channels = 1;
 writer.addAudioStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MP3, channels, sampleRate);

 reader.addListener(writer);
 try {
   while (reader.readPacket() == null)
           ;
 } finally {}
```

I have this error : IllegalArgumentException : stream[0] is not video

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: stream[0] is not video
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:754)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:783)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onVideoPicture(MediaWriter.java:1434)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onVideoPicture(AMediaToolMixin.java:166)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchVideoPicture(MediaReader.java:610)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeVideo(MediaReader.java:519)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:475)
at xuggle.setup(xuggle.java:135)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2117)
at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:193)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2020)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I tried with .mp4 , .mov and .flv movie and I have the same error.

Comment: where's the rest of the code? This is not a minimal running example. Also, looking at http://www.benfarahmand.com/2012/11/tutorial-using-xuggler-in-processing.html?_escaped_fragment_= it looks like you're not making all the necessary calls. Start with that code, reduce it to minimal, then build it up to do what you want?

Comment: Thanks, I build it and I have not error. But when I tried to convert a mp4 i have this error : 2:10:11.715 [Animation Thread] ERROR org.ffmpeg - [png @ 000000000C027950] Specified pix_fmt is not supported
12:10:11.719 [Animation Thread] WARN  com.xuggle.xuggler - Error: could not open codec (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:831)

Comment: best bet: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/xuggler-users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IContainer container = IContainer.make();

```
    int result = container.open(inputFilename, IContainer.Type.READ, null);
     // check if the operation was successful
      if (result<0)
          throw new RuntimeException("Failed to open media file");

      int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();

      int audioStreamId = -1;

      IContainer writer = IContainer.make();
      writer.open(outputFilename, IContainer.Type.WRITE, IContainerFormat.make());



      for (int i=0; i<numStreams; i++) {

          IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
          IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();
          IStreamCoder audioCoder = IStreamCoder.make(IStreamCoder.Direction.ENCODING, coder);

          if( coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO){
              coder.open(IMetaData.make(), IMetaData.make());
              audioStreamId = i;

              ICodec inputCodec = ICodec.findDecodingCodec(ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MP3);
              if (inputCodec == null)
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not find input codec id");

              if (audioStreamId == -1)
                  throw new RuntimeException("could not find audio stream in container: "+inputFilename);

              writer.addNewStream(audioCoder);
              if(writer.writeHeader() == 0)
              {

                  IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
                  while(container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0){

                      if(packet.getStreamIndex() == audioStreamId)
                      {
                          if(coder.isOpen()){

                              writer.writePacket(packet);

                          } else {throw new RuntimeException("Could not open Coder"); }
                      }
                  }
              }else {throw new RuntimeException("Header not Written for writer container.");}
          }

          coder.close(); audioCoder.close();
      }
      writer.writeTrailer();
      writer.close();
```

hope this helps... :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But i have this error 
    15:07:52.399 [Animation Thread] ERROR com.xuggle.xuggler - Error: packet being written to stream that doesn't exist (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:759)

Comment: Gave the code thats working fine for me...it still is working

Comment: Leaving this here for Reference: Regarding the "packet being written to stream that doesn't exist" error, I ran into this error as well.  The stream indexes for the packet and the writer must match.  I ran into this issue because my packet index was set to 1 (the audio stream index rip) and the writer only had one stream which was 0 and was trying to write the packet based on the packet index.  So by adding "packet.setStreamIndex(0);" before the "writer.writePacket(packet);" , the indexes should now match and it should work.